# Completing the Square (Trigonometric Substitution)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I need help completing the square.

The equation is $\sqrt{1-49x^2} \, dx$

I have done
$$-x^2+12x+13+k-k$$
$$k-(x^2-12x-13+49)$$
$$49-(x-6)^2$$

$$u=x-6$$
$$du=dx$$

We then have
$$\sqrt{49-u^2}du$$

We then substitute with $u=7\sin(\theta)$
$$du=7 \cos(\theta)$$
$\theta= \arcsin\left(\frac{x}{7}\right)$

What do I do next?

Comment: Please rephrase your question so it clear what you are asking. How does $-x^2+12x+13$ relate to your integral $\sqrt{1-49x^2}dx$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For the integrand $\sqrt{1-49x^2}$, substitute $x=\frac{\sin(u)}{7}$ and $dx=\frac{\cos(u)}{7}du$.

Then

$$\sqrt{1-49x^2} = \sqrt{1-\sin^2(u)}=\cos(u).$$

Therefore

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int\sqrt{1-49x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{7}\int\cos^2(u)\,du}$$

where $u = \sin^{-1}(7x)$.

For the integral of $\cos^2(u)$ use the trigonometric identity

$$\cos^2(u)= \frac{1}{2}\cos(2u)+\frac{1}{2}.$$